# Arrange $m$ H's and $n$ T's to have exactly $k$ H-runs

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

In an arrangement of $m$ H's and $n$ T's, an uninterrupted sequence of one kind of symbol is called a *run*. (For example: HHHTHHTTTH is a sequence of $6$ H's and $4$ T's which opens with an H-run of length $3$, followed by a T-run of length $1$,an H-run of length $2$, a T-run of length $3$ and an H-run of length $1$). Find the number of arrangements of $m$ H's and $n$ T's in which there are exactly $k$ H-runs.

My solution goes like this :

> We consider $k$ boxes where we will put $m$ H's. Now, between these boxes we have $k-1$ different boxes where we place only T's. We must place at least one T in all those $k-1$ boxes. If the boxes where H is contained are named as $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$, then $x_1+\dots+x_k=m$ and each $x_i\geq 1$. If the boxes where T is contained are named $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{k-1}$ then $y_1+\dots+y_{k-1}=k-1\space \text{or}\space k\space \text{or}\space k+1,...\text{or}\space n$ and each $y_i\geq 1$. Now, the number of solutions of $x_i$ is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$. Now, $y_i$ we have different cases and they are all mutually exclusive, so the total number of solutions are $\binom{k-2}{k-2}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}+\dots +\binom{n-1}{k-2}$. Now, the total number of ways to have $k$ H-runs is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}[\binom{k-2}{k-2}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}+\dots+\binom{n-1}{k-2}].$

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not, where is it going wrong? There may be some posts relating to this topic on this site but I can't seem to find it either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the number of $T$-runs is either $k - 1$, $k$, or $k + 1$.  Let's consider cases.

**Case 1:** $k$ $H$-runs and $k - 1$ $T$-runs.

For this to occur, there must be a run of at least one $T$ in each of the $k - 1$ spaces between runs of at least one $H$.  If $x_i$ is the number of $H$s in the $i$th run, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = m \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  As you found, equation $1$ has
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}$$
solutions in the positive integers.  If $y_j$ is the number of $T$s in the $j$th run, then
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k - 1} = n \tag{2}$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  The number of solutions of equation $2$ in the positive integers is
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 2}$$
Hence, there are
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 2}$$
sequences of $m$ $H$s and $n$ $T$s with $k$ $H$-runs and $k - 1$ $T$-runs.

**Case 2:** $k$ $H$-runs and $k$ $T$-runs

Runs of at least one $H$ must alternate with runs of at least one $T$.  The number of ways of distributing the $H$s is the number of solutions of equation $1$ in the positive integers, which is
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}$$
The number of ways of distributing the $T$s is the number of solutions of the equation
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = n \tag{3}$$
in the positive integers.  Equation $3$ has
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
solutions in the positive integers.  Since the first run either begins with an $H$ or with a $T$, the number of sequences of $m$ $H$s and $n$ $T$s which have $k$ $H$-runs and $k$ $T$-runs is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$

**Case 3:**  $k$ $H$-runs and $k + 1$ $T$-runs

For this to occur, there must be a run of at least one $H$ in each of the $k$ spaces between runs of at least one $T$.

The number of ways of distributing the $H$s is the number of solutions of equation $1$ in the positive integers, which is
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}$$
The number of ways of distributing the $T$s is the number of solutions of the equation
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k + 1} = n \tag{4}$$
in the positive integers.  Equation $4$ has
$$\binom{n - 1}{k}$$
solutions in the positive integers. Hence, the number of sequences of $m$ $H$s  and $n$ $T$s with $k$ runs of $H$s and $k + 1$ runs of $T$s is
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k}$$

**Total:** Since these three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of sequences of $m$ $H$s and $n$ $T$s which have exactly $k$ $H$-runs is
$$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k}$$
This expression can be simplified using [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).
\begin{align*}
\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 2} & + \binom{2}{1}\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n - 1}{k}\\
& \qquad = \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\left[\binom{n - 1}{k - 2} + 2\binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}\right]\\
& \qquad = \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\left[\binom{n - 1}{k - 2} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}\right]\\
& \qquad = \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\left[\binom{n}{k - 1} + \binom{n}{k}\right]\\
& \qquad = \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\binom{n + 1}{k}
\end{align*}

**Addendum:**  In the comments, you suggested the formula
$$\binom{m - 1}{n - 1}\sum_{a = k - 1}^{n} \binom{a - 1}{k - 2}\binom{n - a + 1}{1}$$
where the term in front of the summation is the number of ways of distributing the $m$ $H$s into $k$ runs, the term $\binom{a - 1}{k - 2}$ is the number of ways of distributing $a$ $T$s to the $k - 1$ runs of tails between successive runs of heads, and $\binom{n - a + 1}{1}$ is the number of ways of distributing the remaining $n - a$ $H$s to the spaces before the first $H$ or after the last $H$ without restriction.

Each of these formulas is correct.  The first term was discussed above.  The number of ways of distributing $a$ $T$s to $k - 1$ runs is the number of solutions in the positive integers of the equation
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k - 1} = a$$
which is
$$\binom{a - 1}{k - 2}$$
The number of ways of distributing the remaining $n - a$ heads to the spaces to the left of the first head or to the right of the last head without restriction is the number of solutions of the equation
$$y_0 + y_k = n - a$$
in the nonnegative integers, which is
$$\binom{n - a + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{n - a + 1}{1}$$

Observe that
$$\sum_{a = k - 1}^{n} \binom{a - 1}{k - 2}\binom{n - a + 1}{1}$$
is the number of ways of selecting $k$ elements from the $(n + 1)$-element set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, a - 1, a, \ldots, n\}$, where we select $k - 2$ elements which are less than $a - 1$, select $a - 1$, and then select one of the $n - (a - 1) = n - a + 1$ elements larger than $a$, where $a$ can vary from $k - 1$ to $n$. Hence,
$$\binom{m - 1}{n - 1}\sum_{a = k - 1}^{n} \binom{a - 1}{k - 2}\binom{n - a + 1}{1} = \binom{m - 1}{n - 1}\binom{n}{k + 1}$$
as required.  Therefore, the formula you wrote in the comments is correct.

That said, the answer I wrote above is easier to work with since there are fewer terms and is easier to simplify since the simplifications rely on Pascal's identity rather than a pivot point.

Comment: Well, $x_1+...+x_k=m$ this is true but, each of these H runs must have atleast 1 T between them. There are $k-1$ spaces between them and we can consider k-1 boxes and each of these box must have atleast one T. Now, all the $n$ number of T's maynot be in those $k-1$ boxes . Those $k-1$ boxes should have atleast k-1 T's in total and atmost  $m$ T's. Now, if we denote those T's by $y_i$ then $y_1+...+y_{k-1}=a$ , where $a=k-1,k,k+1,k+2,...,n$ and we get different number of solutions of $y_i$ s for each value of $a$ and

Comment: we get the total number of ways as given above in the original post...but I can't seem to get where is it going wrong ?...

Comment: If you use fewer than $n$ $T$s in those $k - 1$ boxes, you also have to distribute the remaining $T$s to up to two additional boxes.  In the case that there is exactly one additional box, you have to consider whether it is to the left or to the right of all the boxes containing $H$s.

Comment: Thanks! So if we consider two boxes for the rest of the T's then $z_1+z_2=n-a$ , where $k-1\leq a\leq n-1$ and hence we will have distinct solutions for $z_1,z_2\geq 0$ .so, the answer becomes $\binom{m-1}{k-1}[\binom{k-2}{k-2}\binom{n-k+1+2-1}{2-1}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}\binom{n-k+2-1}{2-1}+...+\binom{n-1}{k-2}]=\binom{m-1}{k-1}[\binom{k-2}{k-2}\binom{n-k+2}{1}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}\binom{n-k+1}{1}+...+\binom{n-1}{k-2}]$, right?...Does this fix the problem?...

Comment: If $m = 2, n = 3,$ and $k = 2$, then there are six possible sequences: $$HTHTT, HTTHT, HTTTH, THTHT, THTTH, TTHTH$$ My formula gives $\binom{2 - 1}{2 - 1}\binom{3 + 1}{2} = \binom{1}{1}\binom{4}{2} = 6$, as expected.  If I am reading your formula correctly, it gives $\binom{2 - 1}{2 - 1}\left[\binom{2 - 2}{ 2 - 2}\binom{3 - 2 + 2}{1} +  \binom{2 - 1}{2 - 2}\binom{3 - 2 + 1}{2 - 0} + \binom{3 - 1}{2 - 2}\binom{3 - 3}{2 - 2}\right] = \binom{1}{1}\left[\binom{0}{0}\binom{3}{0} + \binom{1}{0}\binom{2}{0} + \binom{2}{0}\binom{0}{0}\right] = 3$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Your formula $$\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}\sum_{a = k - 1}^{n} \binom{a - 1}{k - 2}\binom{n - a + 1}{1} = \binom{m - 1}{n - 1}\binom{n}{k - 1}$$ by [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), which is how I knew to look for a counterexample.  That said, I have not been able to identify a flaw in your reasoning.  You did assume that the number of solutions of the equations $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k - 1} = a$ in the positive integers and $z_1 + z_2 = n - a$ in the nonnegative integers are independent, which might be the issue.

Comment: Thank you! But the example u showed ...I think something is wrong with the calculation portion where u used my formula to calculate the result ...if u substitute $m=2,n=3,k=2$ then the expression becomes $\binom{1}{1}[\binom{0}{0}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{1}{0}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{0}]=6$ same as ur result, so I think my formula holds valid too ,atleast as it seems from that example ....

Comment: Yes, I misread your formula when I did the example.  I also overlooked a condition needed to use Vandermonde's identity.  I have updated my answer to show that your formula is equivalent to mine.

Comment: @Thanks a lot! I do get it now...Thank you!...